# How to get page with list of all authors on Amazon

Tags: amazon-product-api

I need to get a page with a list of ALL authors in certain genres.
(ie like finding all sellers in certain category)

Here are examples:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/other/ref=sr_sa_p_lbr_one_browse-bin?rh=n%3A133140011%2Cn%3A%21133143011%2Cn%3A7078878011%2Cn%3A154606011%2Cn%3A668010011&bbn=7078878011&sort=featured-rank&pickerToList=lbr_one_browse-bin&ie=UTF8&qid=1480374583

https://www.amazon.com/gp/search/other/?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A17&pickerToList=lbr_one_browse-bin

How can I find these pages for ALL genres I want?
Is there some advanced search page I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a search by author API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_SearchingbyAuthor.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link!

I have no idea how to code with the APIs etc. 
Are you for hire or do you know anyone who can help me get the data I need?